# Shift Cipher Range out of Bounds

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to implement a Shift Cipher, which means, shift every character in a string by an amount. The method I wrote correctly replaces the first letter, but on the second iteration it throws a `Range out of bounds` exception.

`original = @"rt"` The first time `r` is replaced by `w`. `t` isn't replaced by `y` the second time.

`shift = 5`

```
#define LETTER_POS 97
#define ALPHABET_LENGTH 26

- (NSString*)encode:(NSString*)original withShift:(int)shift {

    NSMutableString* encoded = [NSMutableString stringWithString:original];
    for (int i=0; i < [encoded length]; i++) {
        char oriChar = [encoded characterAtIndex:i];
        if (oriChar == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        char encChar = ((oriChar - LETTER_POS) + shift) % ALPHABET_LENGTH + LETTER_POS;
        NSRange range = {i, i+1};
        [encoded replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , encChar]];

    }
    return encoded;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSRange has a location, and a length. You are using i+1 as the length, so in your second iteration you are asking for characters past the end of the string. Your range should be {i, 1}.